# Groovy Match Row and Return Column

Tags: groovy

First of all I'm a Groovy newbie. I've only ever done small adjustments to scripts.

I'm working on an object that I'll be using as part of a Jenkins shared library. The idea is to have something generic that can return values based on what's passed to it.

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

/**
 * Given matchingValue in matchingColumn return the value in returnColumn
 * Use verifyValue first to confirm the value is present
 * @param matchingValue The value that is in matchingColumn
 * @param matchingColumn The column to search
 * @param returnColumn The column to return
 * @return The value in returnColumn in the row of matchingValue
 * @see #matchValue(String)
 */
Object matchValue(String matchingValue, String matchingColumn, String returnColumn) {
    new File('test.csv').withReader { f ->
      def data = new CsvParser().parse(f)
      data.findAll{ (it.${matchingColumn} as String) == "${matchingValue}" }.each{return it.${returnColumn} }
    }
}

def match = matchValue('apple','type','origin')
println "${match}"
```

Contents of test.csv:

```
type,color,origin
apple,red,tree
banana,yellow,ground
avacado,green,ground
lemon,yellow,tree
```

When I run this script I get:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.xlson.groovycsv.PropertyMapper.$() is applicable for argument types: (csvmap$_matchValue_closure1$_closure2$_closure4) values: [csvmap$_matchValue_closure1$_closure2$_closure4@3f3c966c]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), wait()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.xlson.groovycsv.PropertyMapper.$() is applicable for argument types: (csvmap$_matchValue_closure1$_closure2$_closure4) values: [csvmap$_matchValue_closure1$_closure2$_closure4@3f3c966c]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), wait()
    at csvmap$_matchValue_closure1$_closure2.doCall(csvmap.groovy:17)
    at csvmap$_matchValue_closure1.doCall(csvmap.groovy:17)
    at csvmap.matchValue(csvmap.groovy:15)
    at csvmap.run(csvmap.groovy:21)
```

I'm assuming it's because of the dynamic column names but I don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major problems:

- Accessing an property by name is not done via `it.${prop}`, but by
  `it."${prop}"` -- note the quotes
- `each` is used for side effects; assuming you just want to return the
  first match, you want `find` instead of `findAll`+`each`.

E.g.

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def matchValue(String matchingValue, String matchingColumn, String returnColumn) {
    new File('test.csv').withReader { f ->
        def data = new CsvParser().parse(f)
        data.find{ 
            (it."${matchingColumn}" as String) == "${matchingValue}" 
        }?."${returnColumn}"
    }
}

def match = matchValue('apple','type','origin')
println match
// → tree
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!